# How to detect if excel has used any filter in openpyxl

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl, minidom

I am using [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) python library to read excel sheets.

As we know we may have filters in excel. I need to check whether my excel sheet has used any filters using openpyxl.

see this

[image: pic].

I am reading the xml like below.

```
    import openpyxl
    self.work_book = openpyxl.load_workbook(self.file_name, data_only=True)
    print(self.work_book.sheetnames)  -- > print all sheet name
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started by reading the documentation about sorting and filtering at [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html?highlight=filter#). After seeing that there was an `auto_filter` property on the `Worksheet` object it looks like you can access that property to find the filters

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

work_book = load_workbook('path_to_file')
work_sheet = work_book.active

if(len(work_sheet.auto_filter.filterColumn) > 0 ):
    print('Hello')
```

There is also some more detailed documentation about the [AutoFilter](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.filters.html) object too

Let me know if this helps.