# When reading an excel file in Python can we know which column/field is filtered

Tags: python

I want to capture the field or column name that is filtered in the excel file when reading through python. I saw that we can also capture only the filtered rows by using openpyxl and using hidden == False ([How to import filtered excel table into python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46002159/how-to-import-filtered-excel-table-into-python)). In my project it is important to identify which field/column is filtered in the excel file. Is it possible? and how to achieve?
Adding an example.

```
pip install openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

 wb = load_workbook('test_filter_column.xlsx')
 ws = wb['data']
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

This is non hidden data
while if the gender column is filtered below[image: [![enter image description here][2]][2] this.]

So what I am expecting is my output should be giving gender as that is filtered. If more than one field is filtered then expecting to provide all the filtered column names.

Comment: @floatingpurr is it possible to get the filtered column name here in the above case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52755905/how-to-detect-if-excel-has-used-any-filter-in-openpyxl), but adapted to your case, and also accounting for when there are multiple filters:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

# Load workbook
wb = load_workbook('/path/to/xlsx')
# Extract sheet
ws = wb['data']

# Create a dict to store relevant info
filters = {}

# Get the ID of the columns that are filtered
filters['col_id'] = [col.col_id for col in ws.auto_filter.filterColumn]

# Get the letter of the columns that are filtered
# This appears to be one-indexed, but get_column_letter
# is zero indexed
filters['col_letter'] = [get_column_letter(col + 1) for col in filters['col_id']]

# Extract the column name - assuming that it is
# given in row 1 of the column
filters['col_name'] = [ws[f'{col}1'].value for col in filters['col_letter']]

# Get the values of the filters being used
filters['filter_values'] = [col.filters.filter for col in ws.auto_filter.filterColumn]

print(filters)
```

Output:

```
{'col_id': [3], 'col_letter': ['D'], 'col_name': ['gender'], 'filter_values': [['F']]}
```

I think this covers the examples you gave, and hopefully shows some other info you might want too.

Answer (score 0):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('hello.xlsx')
ws = wb['S1']
filter_features = []
for column in ws.iter_cols(min_col=1, max_col=ws.max_column):
    if column[0].hidden == False:
       for col in filter_features:
          print(f"{col}")
       
filter_features.append(column[0].column_letter)
```

This will help you. Moreover, if you want to find filter rows then you must see
[Filtered Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63085533/python-openpyxl-how-to-iterate-through-1-rows-columns-to-find-a-value)

Comment: The code seems to look for columns that are not hidden and not for columns with filters applied. But I would like to identify the field which is filtered like the above example where gender is filtered. So the output should give gender